# Get text in a String at a certain position between []

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm doing a guitar tablature program in WPF and I want to show the corresponding Chord on mouse hover. (in a messagebox will do)

I already have my cursor position in a Int called: cursorPos, which returns the number of the hovered letter position in the string.

My problem is that I need the **Whole Chord** between **[ and ]**

My string looks like this:  `string myString = "[Em] I've been a m[C]iner for a h[D]eart of g[G]old."`

In this case a "cursorPos" of 19 20 or 21 would give me **[C]**

Btw. **Chords** can have from **1 to 10** letter **(like [G#m9(maj7)])**

Comment: What have you tried? Did you received errors? My first approach would be to look back and ahead for the markers ([ and ]) and with those indices you can get easily anything between them (regardless of the length)

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to find all instances of your chords (i.e., substrings between `[` and `]` in your string). There are a myriad ways of doing this, this is one such example tailored to your situation. This is, of course, assuming that you won't have nested brackets.

First, I'm using a class to hold each of your chords. The `IsInRange()` method will tell you whether the chord is in the cursor position you pass to it.

```
public class Chord
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public int Start { get; set; }
    public int End { get; set; }
    public bool IsInRange(int cursorPos)
    {
        return cursorPos >= Start && cursorPos <= End;
    }
}
```

Now let's write a function to extract all the chords in a string.

```
static List<Chord> GetChords(string str)
{
    var chords = new List<Chord>();

    var chord = new Chord();
    var count = 0;
    foreach (var ch in str)
    {
        if (ch == '[')
        {
            chord = new Chord
            {
                Start = count
            };
            chord.Value += ch;
        }
        else if (ch == ']')
        {
            chord.End = count;
            chord.Value += ch;
            chords.Add(new Chord() { Value = chord.Value, Start = chord.Start, End = chord.End });
            chord = null;
        }
        else
        {
            if (chord != null)
                chord.Value += ch;
        }

        count++;
    }

    return chords;
}
```

Now, you can pass any string to this and get the chords, and make use of `IsInRange()` function to check if a given cursor position corresponds to a chord.

```
string myString = "[Em] I've been a m[C]iner for a h[D]eart of g[G#m9(maj7)]old.";
var chords = GetChords(myString);
```

Let's see if cursor position 19 returns anything.

```
var chordAt19 = chords.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsInRange(19));
```

Since we do indeed have a chord at 19 it will return it.
If there isn't (for example if we passed 12 into it) it will return null.

Comment: This Solution seems to always return "GuitarMate.Editor+Chord" I'm not sure why